# Php code for page break after full stop near to 100 words

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a test area which is dynamic text from database may be of thousands of words.
I want it to break and make a paragraph of each with full stop near 100(any length) words.
I am able to make break after 100 words but not with full stop.
To make break after 100(any length) words I used the following function.

```
function TrimString($String, $Length)
{
    if(strlen($String) > $Length)
    {
        $Temp[0] = substr($String, 0, $Length);
        $Temp[1] = substr($String, $Length);
        $SpacePos = strpos($Temp[1], ' ');
        if($SpacePos !== FALSE)
        {
            return $Temp[0].substr($Temp[1], 0, $SpacePos);
        }
    }
    return $String;
}
```

example:-

```
function TrimString($String, $Length){
    if(strlen($String)<=$Length){
        $stringValue=$String;
    } else {
        $stringValue=substr($String,0,$Length) . '.';
    }
    return $stringValue;
}
$m=50;
$a="I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. ";
$data=TrimString($a,$m);
echo $data;
```

It provides me the answer

```
I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I .
```

but i need the answer

```
I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy.
```

So can you help me to find the full stop near to the length provided to that function and to break the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add full stop`(.)` here like

```
 return $Temp[0].substr($Temp[1], 0, $SpacePos).".";
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<?php
function TrimString($String, $Length){
    if(strlen($String)<=$Length){
        $stringValue=$String;
    } else {
        $new_l = strpos ($String , ".", $Length);
        $Length = $new_l+1;
        $stringValue=substr($String,0,$Length);
    }
    return $stringValue;
}
$m=50;
$a="I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. ";
$data=TrimString($a,$m);
echo $data;
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy. I am a boy.
```

Comment: what you are doing that is right in another case for putting . after the length but I want to know the full stop near 100 words or according to the length and I want to break there. Any solution please.

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 can you put an example?

Comment: ok I have edited my question with example you can look over there

Comment: do you have any idea to use a word instead of '.'

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 didin't understand instead of `.`. if you have another question post it.

Comment: what you want instead of it.

Comment: $new_l = strpos ($String , "manakamana", $Length); I want this but it only takes only one letter

Answer (score 0):

```
function TrimString($String, $Length){
 if(strlen($String)<=$Length){ 
  $stringValue=$String; 
 } else { 
  $stringValue=substr($String,0,$Length) . '.'; 
 }
 return $stringValue;
}

you are looking like this:

function TrimString($String, $Length){
 if(strlen($String)<=$Length){ 
  $stringValue=$String; 
 } else { 
  $stringValues=substr($String,0,$Length) . '.'; 
  $lengths=strrpos($stringValues,"."); 
  $stringValue=substr($stringValus,0,$lengths).".";
 }
 return $stringValue;
}
```

Comment: i think this is the case to put full stop after the length. I want to know the full stop near the length provided.